# Java service won't start when using srvany.exe and Java 8

Tags: windows, java, windows-services

I have a couple of Java applications that I run as services on my work machine using `srvany.exe`.  [After resolving a previous issue](https://superuser.com/q/374147/17529), this system hasn't caused any major problems for us.  However, after getting an upgraded workstation and setting everything up, the Java no longer works.  I see `srvany.exe` in Process Explorer, but no child Java process.  Because of corporate IT policies, my default Java runtime is Java 8, but I also have the Java 7 JDK for development purposes.  If I change the `srvany` properties to use `java.exe` from the JDK, everything works fine.  How can I get `srvany` to run a Java application using Java 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe`.  I can't seem to find why `java.exe` no longer works, while `javaw.exe` does, since the release notes don't mention the runtime executables.  It may have something to do with `java.exe` expecting to have a command line/standard out, which isn't really the case with service.